# How to pass values from a list in request of jmeter request

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm extracting 2 two set of values in two different lists from a JSON response using JSON extractor

[image: Extractor1]

[image]

I'm looping through values of list1 using a foreach loop, so i can easily get values from list1 one-by-one:

[image]

But I want to send values from list2 in one of the request inside this foreach loop.
How can I get values from list2 one-by-one so that I send it as a parameter:

[image]

This HTTP request will be called for each item in list. I want to add value from list2 to `lastUpdated` parameter in given HTTP request.How can I do it?

I did some research and got to know that we can use Beanshell PreProcessor for this task. I added following code in Beanshell PreProcessor:

```
idx = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("item_no"))-1;
vars.put("date", vars.get("list2")[idx]);
```

And tried passing date as follows:

```
{"qId":"${q_oid}","items":[{"itemId":"${qi_id}","lastUpdated":"${date}"}]}
```

But I'm getting blank in the `lastUpdated` arg. 
Note : I have added 'date' in the user defined variables of the test plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

list2 variable are saved as: list_1 list_2 list_3,...

So change the variable name inside [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller:)

```
vars.put("date", vars.get("list2_" + idx));
```

> So for example when the input variable has the name inputVar, the following variables should have been defined:
>
> inputVar_1 = wendy
>   inputVar_2 = charles
>   inputVar_3 = peter
>   inputVar_4 = john

Notice also JMeter holds special variable inside ForEach Controller:

> JMeter will expose the looping index as a variable named **jm**__idx. So for example, if your Loop Controller is named FEC, then you can access the looping index through ${__jm__FEC__idx}. Index starts at 0